# Strings with Pipe character in them - how to avoid them being mistaken for logical OR?

Tags: powershell

```
$word = '{Quit|Discontinue|Stop|Cease|Give Up}'
$htmltitle1 = $word -replace  '{Quit|Discontinue|Stop|Cease|Give Up}', 'Give Up'
```

$htmltitle1

```
Give Up|Give Up|Give Up|Give Up|Give Up
```

How do I force powershell to take the text to be replaced as an exact string instead of being a logic OR?

It should just be:

```
Give Up
```

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$htmltitle1 = $word -replace [regex]::escape('{Quit|Discontinue|Stop|Cease|Give Up}'), 'Give Up'
```

Comment: It works! thanks a lot. So the only way to do this is to use the .net regex ?

Comment: You can manually do what [regex]::escape would do with this particular expression, which is to backslashes before regex meta characters: \{Quit\|Discontinue\|Stop\|Cease\|Give\ Up}